# How can i pass dynamic url of an image to li tag attribute in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a li tag which have data-thumb attribute. I want to pass dynamic image url to this attribute.

```
<li data-thumb="img/d2.jpg">
```

after rendering it in the browser i get

```
<li><img src="img/d2.jpg" class="" draggable="false"></li>
```

automatically but the thing i want is passing only path to img folder and point to d2.jpg image inside it, i have tried webroot function but it does not give the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li data-thumb="<?= $this->Url->build('/img/d2.jpg"); ?>">
```

generate html element like:

```
<li data-thumb="/img/d2.jpg">
```

Read more: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html